# how to pass component props from React to Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am constantly getting an error message when trying to pass the props (which is just a string) of the component(from Table component) to redux via connect,

The error output I am getting is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

```
  13 | 
  14 | const getTableData = (state) =>{
  15 |   return{
> 16 |     fieldNames: state[this.props.tableHead]
  17 |   }
  18 | }
  19 |
```

Table component is called in a component with props:

```
<Table data = {'contacts'} tableHead = {'contactsKeyNames'}/>
```

Where Table component is:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../styles/App.css';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Table extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <div> hi </div>
    )
  }  
}

const getTableData = (state) =>{
  return{
    fieldNames: state[this.props.tableHead]
  }
}

export default connect(getTableData)(Table);
```

and where the redux store is:

```
const initState = {
  contacts:[
    {
      company: 'Rapid Precision Mfg.',
      title: 'Quality Engineer',
      firstName: 'Dongyob',
      lastName: 'Lee',
      officePh: '',
      ext: '',
      cell: '669-294-0910',
      email: 'dyl4810@gmail.com'   
    },
    {
      company: 'Facebook',
      title: 'Frontend Developer',
      firstName: 'Edward',
      lastName: 'Simmons',
      officePh: '408-516-4662',
      ext: '003',
      cell: '669-252-4251',
      email: 'edwardsimmons@gmail.com'   
    },
    {
      company: 'Amazon',
      title: 'Data Scientist',
      firstName: 'Harry',
      lastName: 'Davis',
      officePh: '',
      ext: '',
      cell: '408-344-2110',
      email: 'harrydavis0@gmail.com'   
    },
    {
      company: 'Google',
      title: 'Googler',
      firstName: 'Katherine',
      lastName: 'Jones',
      officePh: '408-963-7156',
      ext: '846',
      cell: '408-828-0550',
      email: 'katherinejones0@gmail.com'   
    },
    {
      company: 'Alibaba',
      title: 'Scammer',
      firstName: 'Eric',
      lastName: 'Brown',
      officePh: '510-663-5552',
      ext: '462',
      cell: '408-644-0110',
      email: 'ericbrown@gmail.com'   
    },
  ],
  contactsKeyNames:{
    company: 'Company',
    title: 'Title',
    firstName: 'First Name',
    lastName: 'Last Name',
    officePh: 'Office',
    ext: 'Ext',
    cell: 'Cell',
    email: 'Email'
  }
};
const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  return state;
};

export default rootReducer;
```

I tried to bind this to prop by setting up constructor as below but didn't work.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props) 

    this.props = this.props.bind(this)
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?
Help!

Comment: this in your getTableData is not refering to your component instance. Rephrase what you're trying to do so is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [connect docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate). You need to use the ownProps argument to access tableHead:

```
const getTableData = (state, ownProps) =>{
  return{
   fieldNames: state[ownProps.tableHead]
  }
};
```

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You should also make sure that your component is being registered and passed the Provider properly.

Comment: I don't think you need the constructor fyi

Answer (score 1):

It is more idiomatic to use mapStateToProps so its easy to figure out what's going on. Also why not just add in contactsKeyNames directly, like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  contactsKeyNames: state.contactsKeyNames
})
```

In my opinion, this is much easier to follow...

You can then refer to contactsKeyNames like so:

```
class Table extends React.Component{
  render() {
    const { contactsKeyNames } = this.props;
    ...
```

Comment: I am trying to make table component modular so that it can serve as a data table for any data passed onto it